# How to resolve PHP bug #67481 (Opcache uses wrong file from cache)?

Tags: php

I am trying to resolve php bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67481 on PHP Version 5.6.29-0+deb8u1.

They say that:
This does not happen when opcache.validate_timestamps is set to a non-zero value.
and
It can also be worked around by using `require __DIR__ . '/../src/bootstrap.php';`

My `opcache.validate_timestamps` is `1` and script uses `__DIR__` variable. And the bug still occurs. How is this possible?

Comment: As you correctly pointed, this bug clearly says it doesn't happen if opcache.validate_timestamps is not zero. So why do you think what you're experiencing is related to that problem? Anyway, the workaround is well described there - just use `__DIR__` or `realpath`.

Comment: That's the problem. My opcache.validate_timestamps is not zero, it's 1. And the bug still here. Also I use __DIR__ or realpath and the bug is also still here.